# How to avoid two compose mail at a time in Outlook

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I am trying to customize Outlook through C# code addin. It's working but when opening two or more compose mails (through new mail), some problems appear. So I want to avoid opening of two or more compose mail at a same time in Outlook. My Outlook version is 2013.

In the code below, I try to send a link of attached file at the time of the send click event. If the person opens two or more compose mail at a same time this will collapse (I wrote a lot of code out from this in my project to get link of attached code and for others). How can I avoid two compose mail or maintain different sessions for two compose mail dialogues?

```
void Application_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
{
    int attachcountbs=0;
    StringBuilder sendinglink = new StringBuilder();
    string[] comingstrbuilder = Convert.ToString(SPForm.urlofattach).Split('\n');
    Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
    Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);           
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    //sb.AppendLine("-------------Internal Use-------------<br/>");
    //sb.AppendLine("<a href='" + Class1.test + "'>" + Class1.test + "</a>");

    if (Item is Outlook.MailItem)
    {
        Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem)Item;
        Outlook.NameSpace session = mail.Session;
        attachcountbs = mail.Attachments.Count;

        int arraycount = comingstrbuilder.Count();
        int checkattach=1;
        for (int i = 0; i < arraycount; i++)
        {
            if (attachcountbs < checkattach)
            {
                break;
            }
            if (comingstrbuilder[i].Contains(mail.Attachments[checkattach].DisplayName))
            {

            //}
            //if (comingstrbuilder[i] == mail.Attachments[checkattach].DisplayName)
            //{
                sendinglink.AppendLine(comingstrbuilder[i]);
                checkattach++;
            }
        }

        if (mail.Attachments.Count == 0)
        {
            mail.HTMLBody = "";
        }
        else
        {
            mail.HTMLBody += "-------------Internal Use-------------<br/>";

            //mail.HTMLBody += "<a href='" + Class1.test + "'>" + Class1.test + "</a>";
            //mail.HTMLBody += SPForm.urlofattach.ToString();
            mail.HTMLBody += sendinglink.ToString();
            SPForm.urlofattach.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Trying to stop the user from using Outlook in the way that they want to seems to be the ... *wrong* ... solution. I'd suggest focussing more on making your code deal with the situation gracefully.

Comment: than u.....i got some other logic with my code to handle more new mail window........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have noticed the following code:

```
 Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
```

There is no need to create a new Outlook Application instance in the ItemSend event handler. Instead, you need to use the Application property of the add-in class.

The Display method accepts a boolean parameter which allows to display a modal window. In that case a user should close such windows before opening another inspector windows. Just pass true to the method.

Also the single Outlook instance can be at the same time, so there can be only one session.